# Argon2 5 threads is slower than 4 threads

Tags: php, php-password-hash, argon2-ffi

I am using https://github.com/charlesportwoodii/php-argon2-ext to play around with Argon2.
While i was playing with the parameters I noticed that the speed is not decreasing per core accordingly.

See a graph here:
[Time is in seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7lqu.png)

Code a ran:

```
for($threads = 1; $threads <= 8; $threads++) {
    $time1 = microtime(true);

    $options = [
        'm_cost' => 65536,//64MB
        't_cost' => 64,
        'threads' => $threads
    ];

    $password = "secret";
    argon2_hash($password, HASH_ARGON2I, $options);

    $time2 = microtime(true);
    $execution_time = ($time2 - $time1);
    printf("execution time with $threads threads: " . $execution_time . " seconds\n");
}
```

My system:
Debian 9,
8GB RAM,
i7-4710HQ @ 2.50GHz

Can somebody explain this or can think of an reason?

Comment: Your processor has 4 cores, and hyperthreading is not "2x physical cores" like many people believe. So the reason is that you're attempting to run more threads than you have processors.

Comment: Also your benchmark consists of a single execution for each configuration and is highly susceptible to interference from other activity on the system, and even then when you're running a benchmark like this there should be literally _nothing_ else running on the system beyond the OS.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Sammitch. Makes sense about hyperthreading indeed. And yes I am aware about my "benchmark" and thus should be taken with a grain of salt.